# Active/Popular Google Code Django projects

Tags: django, open-source, google-code

I am python/django developer. As a part of improving my knowledge and felt like I need to "contribute" to the field of open-source, I started looking for django projects in [code.google.com](http://code.google.com). There were many. I am not very sure which ones are popular and which needs help. Can you help me out in this direction, so that I instead of using many open-source softwares(since 3 years), **start contributing to atleast one of them**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that rather looking for an active or popular one to contribute to you rather find a project that you would use yourself and contribute to that.

Using a product or project yourself will provide better motivation to get involved and provide first hand experience on what needs improving.

And of course, working on something you are passionate about is also much more fun than something random!

Comment: Well said @Miller, I started writing my own product. Its called ZeShare(Please dont worry about the name). Its here: https://github.com/madhav/zeshare

Answer (score 0):

Give your time to django.  Help them get 1.1 out the door and all of us who love django  will shower you with praise.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) as a very worthwhile candidate. Overall though, I agree with Andree Miller's answer that you should try finding a project which you, yourself use and feel needs improvements.

Good luck!